# Value used in the formula is of wrong data type

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have one cell type “date” as 19/5/2020

Another cell “number” type .

The the number of dates being calculated as

```
    =datedif(cell, today(), “d”) 
     Example like

    =datedif(e12, today(), “d”)
```

The strange thing is for few records it’s working fine. However for few records it’s showing.

```
     #value!
```

It’s strange, What the problem could be? How to fix this?
Using excel 2016. Thanks.

Comment: Check those records - are there odd spaces or errors?

Comment: DATEDIF finds the difference between two dates.The error you see is the one you get if one of them isn't. Since TODAY() is a date, `Cell` or `E12` isn't. Most probably its a fake date. That is a date that looks like a date but isn't. So, the question is, "What looks like a date but isn't?" aka "What's a date?" A date is a number which can be displayed in many ways and used in calculations like the one you attempt. A fake date looks the same but isn't a number. Change the cell format of a fake date to `Number` and it will still be a string. A real date will show it's number.

Comment: You could change your formula to `=datedif(E12*1, today(), “d”)` forcing a calculation on the cell - if it can be converted to a number (date) it will.  Another way is to multiply all the values in column E by 1 using the PasteSpecial method.